# How to list CloudWatch metrics using boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Does someone have a boto3 example of how to get the same results as this AWS CLI command:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace "CWAgent" --metric-name "LogicalDisk % Free Space" --query Metrics[*]
```

I am trying to get the value for these Dimensions:

```
instance, InstanceId, ImageId, objectname, InstanceType
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
import boto3

# Create CloudWatch client
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

obj = []
response = client.list_metrics(
    Namespace='CWagent',
    MetricName='LogicalDisk % Free Space',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'instance',
            'Value': obj
        },
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': obj
        },
        {
            'Name': 'ImageId',
            'Value': obj
        },
        {
            'Name': 'objectname',
            'Value': obj
        },
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceType',
            'Value': obj
        },
    ],
    NextToken='string'
)

for r in response:
    a = instance
    b = InstanceId
    c = ImageId
    d = objectname
    e = InstanceType
    print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Comment: So you get any errors?

Comment: Also, could you show what is the outcome of the CLI command?

Comment: This is the output of the boto3 logice:

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 32, in <module>
    NextToken='string'
\client.py", line 276, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
\client.py", line 559, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
\client.py", line 607, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
\validate.py", line 297, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:

Comment: And:

Invalid type for parameter Dimensions[0].Value, value: [], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter Dimensions[1].Value, value: [], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter Dimensions[2].Value, value: [], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter Dimensions[3].Value, value: [], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter Dimensions[4].Value, value: [], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Comment: This is the output of the AWS CLI commaind that lists the dimensions, but just for one instance:

LogicalDisk % Free Space 
DIMENSIONS      instance        C:
DIMENSIONS      InstanceId      i-1234567891315f72b
DIMENSIONS      ImageId ami-1234567899f928462
DIMENSIONS      objectname      LogicalDisk
DIMENSIONS      InstanceType    r5.large
LogicalDisk % Free Space 
DIMENSIONS      instance        D:
DIMENSIONS      InstanceId      i-1234567891315f72b
DIMENSIONS      ImageId ami-1234567899f928462
DIMENSIONS      objectname      LogicalDisk
DIMENSIONS      InstanceType    r5.large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boto3 code will access the CWAgent Metrics Dimensions form an individual instance or all instances on how you set the instances variable:
`

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['MY_INSTANCE_NAME']}])

#instances = ec2.instances.all()

cw = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

for i in instances:
    a = i.instance_id

# List metrics through the pagination interface
    paginator = cw.get_paginator('list_metrics')
    for response in paginator.paginate(
        MetricName='LogicalDisk % Free Space',
        Namespace='CWAgent',
        Dimensions=[
        {'Name': 'instance'},
            {'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': a},
            {'Name': 'ImageId'},
            {'Name': 'objectname'},
            {'Name': 'InstanceType'}
        ],):
            print(response['Metrics'])
```

`